# Flash Animation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I want to create a construction page for one of the site with a glass filling with water.... now the concept is the site is going to be launched next year.... So I need the glass to be filled by next yr... with the countdown timer... is there any good example or a way of doing this.... I'm not that good in actionscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's pretty simple, you first should learn how to create a [preloader](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oC31Pc5SCHM). If this works, then you should make your mask dependable of the date and not of the bytes loaded. (bytesTotal would be 365, bytesLoaded 365 minus days left) Let's say you're at day 25 of 365, then your mask should be 100/365*25%. So 6,85% of the water would be visible. Getting a date in flash is no problem, so the calculation should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

My idea: do the glass animation as stylish as you want using after effects (or a similar tool), try to use at least 365 frames.

Export each frame as png, and every day, from your page, load a different image.